# radius of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^22^{\large -n!} x^{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the radius of convergence of the series

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^22^{\large -n!} x^{n!} 
$$
?

**Answer:**

If the series was

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^22^{\large -n!} x^{n}
$$

then I could apply Hardamard Formula. But since there are $x^{n!}$ instead of $x^n$ I got stuck right here.

Help me doing this using Cauchy Hadamard formula
.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$
a_{n!} = n^2 \cdot 2^{-n!}, a_k = 0 \quad [k \notin \{j!\}_{j \in \mathbb N^*}],
$$
then the series is $\sum a_j x^j$. Now use Cauchy-Hadamard as you want:
$$
\frac 1R = \overline {\lim_k} |a_k|^{1/k} = \overline {\lim_n } |a_{n!}|^{1/n!} = \overline {\lim_n} (n^2)^{1/n!} 2^{-1} = \frac 12,
$$
where
$$
1 \leqslant (n^2)^{1/n!} \leqslant (n^2)^{1/n^2} \to 1 \quad [n \to \infty]. 
$$
Hence $R = 2$.

**UPDATE**

At endpoints $\pm 2$, when $x = 2$, the series becomes $\sum n^2 = +\infty$. At $x = -2$, since $n!$ are even numbers for $n \geqslant 2$, the series becomes $-1 + \sum_2^\infty n^2 = +\infty$.

Comment: Does the series converges at $ \ x= \pm 2 $ ?

Comment: @yourmath Assume you meant $x = \pm 2$. Just plug these values into the expression of the series and you would see immediately.

Comment: At $ \ x=\pm 2 , \ |a_{n!} x^{n!}|=|n^2 2^{n!} \cdot (\pm 2)^{n!}|=|n^2 2^{2 n!} | $ . Now  , $ (n^2 2^{2n!})^{1/n!} \ =4n^{2/n!} \to 4 \ as \ n \to \infty \ $ . so does not converge

Answer (score 5):

Note that$$\left\lvert\frac{(n+1)^22^{-(n+1)!}x^{(n+1)!}}{n^22^{-n!}x^{n!}}\right\rvert=\frac{n+1}n\left\lvert\frac x2\right\rvert^{n\times n!}$$and that therefore$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert\frac{2^{-(n+1)!x^{(n+1)!}}}{2^{-n!}x^{n!}}\right\rvert=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }|x|<2\\+\infty&\text{ if }|x|>2.\end{cases}$$So, the radius of convergence is $2$.

Comment: @DavideMorgante I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: This is nice answer. But i will request you to answer the question using Cauchy-Hadamard formula.

Comment: Does the series converges at $ \ x=\pm 2$?

Comment: At $ \ x=\pm 2 , \ |a_{n!} x^{n!}|=|n^2 2^{n!} \cdot (\pm 2)^{n!}|=|n^2 2^{2 n!} | $

Comment: @yourmath The series diverges at $\pm2$, since the sequence $(n2^{-n!}x^{n!})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ doesn't converge to $0$ then.